# Communication between zephyr bioharness and external devices (Android)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need android code to get the data from external sensor that is recognized by the zephyr bioharness module (the biomodule knows the MAC address of the external sensor).  I know that I should use bluetooth peripheral message, but I need examples.

Comment: is it a BLE peripheral device?

Comment: No, it is not BLE peripheral device.